# Kernel Panic and continuous beeping when restarting

Tags: kernel-panic

I have a MBP (mid 2010, 13") and this is the usual kernel panic that I see each time that it restarts (sometimes it doesn't restart and it makes a continuous beeping).

Kernel Panic log here:
https://jpst.it/Rvu7

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the contents of the panic log in the question?  This will help others, who might have a similar problem, with searching and finding answers.

Comment: When you state "continuous beeping", does it pulsate with 3 second intervals? Or is it one long beep?

Comment: Hello @fsb, I tried since the beginning but I couldn't post it because the site said that the content may contain spam.

Comment: Yes, @natemacinnes, more or less 3 seconds (seems like an infinite beeping).

Answer (score 2):

The first step would be to check out [About Mac computer startup tones](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768) and identify which one of these startup tones is the one you're experiencing with your Mid-2010 MBP.

**Please do not guess.** If your startup tone does not match *exactly* one of the ones listed, please comment back and say so and describe which one it is closest to and what the difference is. Unfortunately, not all of the possible startup tones are listed on that page.

Comment: Hello, as I said to @natemacinnes after a short beep it makes an interval of 3 seconds (more or less, I didn't use a stopwatch because the MBP worked fine yesterday) and it beeps again (seems like an infinite loop).

I used your link about tones and the beep looks like this:
_**"1 tone, repeating every 5 seconds: This indicates no RAM is installed."**_
But as I said it's something around 3 or 4 seconds.
Next time I will use a stopwatch.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And it's just the one beep followed by a pause of _x_ seconds followed by another single beep followed by a pause of _x_ seconds and so on and so on? Or is it multiple beeps followed by the pause etc etc?

Comment: Yes, just one tone followed by a pause, no multiple beeps. It's something like that:  **beep** _(pause)_ **beep** _(pause)_ **beep** _(pause)_ and so on. I think it could continue to beep until the battery is charged.

Comment: I have a new kernel panic log: https://justpaste.it/12cr7
This time the MBP restarted without problems (automatically, after some seconds of freezing) and no black screen with beeps, only a kernel panic. I didn't use it so much today (simple navigation, not so much work) but right now (as always) the case is just a little bet hot (especially in the magsafe zone).

Comment: Now the MBP doesn't want to start and it makes the usual **beep** (yes, it is a 5 seconds beep). Here's the video: http://sendvid.com/izdhbyif @Monomeeth.

Comment: This is a common problem seen with MacBook Pro 13" pre-2012. 
It is a result of the logic board not being able to read the RAM. 
In this particular model it can often be caused by pressure, over time, on the bottom case thusly, causing pressure on the logic board.
This issue is solved with a Logic Board replacement and in some rare cases the bottom case. 
To test it yourself, see if you can cause a kernel panic or freeze while appliying some pressure to the center/slightly right side (from the top) of the bottom case.

Comment: To avoid this issue with these MacBook Pros do not make it a habit on using uneven surfaces (knees for example) or picking the unit up with one hand. Additionally, try not to transport it in something with other heavy objects that can apply pressure to the bottom case.

Comment: Ok @natemacinnes, I will try. Just to add some other informations. I can use the MBP for hours, simple navigation or Photoshop, it doesn't matter. The kernel panic appear if I used it for hours (e.g. if I start to use it in the morning the MBP could work, more or less, until the mid of the afternoon, then a kernl panic will freeze the screen and right after it restarts with beeping (and I have to wait until the next day to use it again). What do you think about reballing? In your opinion, it will works? Since I don't think that a new GPU is worth while on MBP from mid 2010. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Mlabuit, my estimate does not change too much from the original diagnosis. You could test another, less likely scenario; one RAM slot on the Mac is faulty. If you are comfortable in doing so, you could remove a RAM stick and using the Mac with one RAM stick in only one slot. If the issue reoccurs, remove the RAM and place it in the other slot. If the issue reoccurs a second time, use the other RAM stick. If the issue reoccurs a third time, then it is 100% a logic board problem, and it will not improve without replacement. How to remove RAM https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201165

Comment: I 100% agree with what @natemacinnes suggests in their last comment (it is what I would do too as the next step in a process of elimination). Also, can I ask whether you're running your MBP connected to an external display?

Comment: Hi @natemacinnes, I tried two times the "pressure trick" and unfortunately "it works". So, your comment reminded me when I carried the MBP around. When I used to bring the charger I always placed it inside the soft cover. Now, I guess, this isn't recommended. Also, today I noticed that if I reset the PRAM the MBP restarts without problems.
**About the RAM:**
I tried one RAM per time in the two slots and it doesn't work (maybe I made a mistake, I tried this when the MBP didn't want to start, maybe I will try when the MBP works well).

Comment: Hi @Mlabuit, great job performing the diagnostics. You have confirmed that it is not the RAM, it is the **logic board**. The issue will not get better, but if you can get it working consistently, and do not move it much it _probably_ will not get worse. Using a soft case is a trade off, it is great to protect from scratches when transporting in bags, but if it means that more pressure is applied to the bag because it takes up more volume in the bag, then it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem seen with MacBook Pro 13" pre-2012. It is a result of the logic board not being able to read the RAM. In this particular model it can often be caused by pressure, over time, on the bottom case thusly, causing pressure on the logic board. This issue is solved with a Logic Board replacement and in some rare cases the bottom case. To test it yourself, see if you can cause a kernel panic or freeze while applying some pressure to the center/slightly right side (from the top) of the bottom case.

To avoid this issue with these MacBook Pros do not make it a habit on using uneven surfaces (knees for example) or picking the unit up with one hand. Additionally, try not to transport it in something with other heavy objects that can apply pressure to the bottom case.

If the Mac does not freeze when applying pressure, you can test the RAM by following these steps:
You could test another, less likely scenario; one RAM slot on the Mac is faulty.

1. Remove a RAM stick and using the Mac with one RAM stick in only one slot.
2. If the issue reoccurs, remove the RAM and place it in the other slot.
3. If the issue reoccurs a second time, use the other RAM stick.
4. If the issue reoccurs a third time, then it is 100% a logic board problem, and it will not improve without replacement.

If at any point the issue does not reoccur with one of the RAM sticks, use that combination of that RAM stick in the working slot only. The Mac will work fine with . only one RAM stick as long as it is > 2GB. You could also upgrade it a larger capacity RAM stick.

How to remove RAM [support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201165](http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201165)

Answer (score 0):

USE codykrieger GFXCARDSTATUS

The NvidiaCard are wrong in all of MacbookPro... :( i sucked it but i found the solve! You need to disable Nvidia and use only the Intel graphic chips!!!!

install it: https://gfx.io/  or instal the older 1.8.1 : https://github.com/codykrieger/gfx.io/find/gh-pages  its better for me because it can disable full Nvidia!!!!

I suck this blackscreen freeze, and i try many thinx (ramreset, diskutil, voltage, reinstal...) and this NVIDIA DISABLE is the best....

... but some app can only use Nvidia (secondary monitor, transmission, games...) and i dont use these...